# Regex removes whitespace and empty line

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to create a program that deciphers a text file into readable text. The encoded text follows two rules, it always begins with either a vowel or consonant, this is represented as C or V, followed by its index position (e.g: V1C1C3, would be "abc")

I created two arrays to contain the vowels and consonants ("0" is at index 0 just so the rest of the array could start at index1):

```
String[] vowels = {"0", "a", "A", "e", "E", "i", "I", "o", "O", "u", "U", "y", "Y"};
String[] cons = {"0","b", "B", "c", "C", "d", "D", "f", "F", "g", "G", "h", "H", "j", "J", "k", "K", "l", "L", "m", "M", "n", "N", "p", "P", "q", "Q", "r", "R", "s", "S", "t", "T", "v", "V", "w", "W", "x", "X", "z", "Z"};
```

I'm using a scanner to separate the code into vowels and consonants, and to also get the index value:

```
while(scan.hasNext()){
    String[] parts = scan.nextLine().split("(?=[CV])");

    for (String part : parts) {
        Scanner num = new Scanner(part).useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
        int value = num.nextInt();

        if(part.charAt(0) == 'C'){
           System.out.print(cons[value]);
        }
        else if (part.charAt(0) == 'V'){
           System.out.print(vowels[value]);
        }
    }
}
```

The encrypted text: V6 C17V7C33V3 V1C23C23C17V3C29 (The result should be: I love apples)

The result I'm getting: Iloveapples

**P.S:** if I have multiple paragraphs of encrypted text, the scanner stops after the first and outputs an error. This doesn't happen if I use "scan.next()" instead of "scan.nextLine()"

Comment: There is nothing in the code to detect and output the missing spaces.

Comment: @AdrianHHH So would you suggest I make a new scanner to check for spaces or add "\\s" within the already existing scanner?

Comment: You need another loop around your parts loop.  Perform a split on spaces, then feed that output into the parts loop.  Print out a space at the end of your new loop.
Alternatively, you could use streams or regex to remap your characters and preserve the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want any part that is not an encoding to remain unchanged, e.g. the spaces in the example given, but could also be symbols such as commas, question marks, etc.

Which means it would be much better to use regex replacement, using regex to locate encodings, i.e. letter `C` or `V` followed by digits.

```java
private static final String VOWELS = "aAeEiIoOuUyY";
private static final String CONSONANTS = "bBcCdDfFgGhHjJkKlLmMnNpPqQrRsStTvVwWxXzZ";
```

```java
// Requires Java 9+
public static String decode(String encodedText) {
    return Pattern.compile("[CV]\\d+").matcher(encodedText)
            .replaceAll(r -> String.valueOf((r.group().charAt(0) == 'V' ? VOWELS : CONSONANTS)
                                            .charAt(Integer.parseInt(r.group().substring(1)) - 1)));
}
```

```java
// For Java 1.4+
public static String decode(String encodedText) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[CV]\\d+").matcher(encodedText);
    while (m.find()) {
        String token = m.group();
        int value = Integer.parseInt(token.substring(1));
        char ch = (token.charAt(0) == 'V' ? VOWELS : CONSONANTS).charAt(value - 1);
        m.appendReplacement(buf, String.valueOf(ch));
    }
    return m.appendTail(buf).toString();
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(decode("V6 C17V7C33V3 V1C23C23C17V3C29"));
System.out.println(decode("C30C11V3 V1C29C15V3C5, \"C36C11V1C31 V1C27V3 V11V7V9 C5V7V5C21C9?\""));
```

*Output*

```
I love apples
She asked, "What are you doing?"
```

---

For completeness, here is a simple unoptimized encoding method, used to create that second example above:

```java
// For Java 1.5+
public static String encode(String plainText) {
    int index;
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {
        char ch = plainText.charAt(i);
        if ((index = VOWELS.indexOf(ch)) != -1)
            buf.append('V').append(index + 1);
        else if ((index = CONSONANTS.indexOf(ch)) != -1)
            buf.append('C').append(index + 1);
        else
            buf.append(ch);
    }
    return (buf.length() == plainText.length() ? plainText : buf.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of this encodes some test phrases.  The second part decodes them, preserving punctuation characters.

```
String[] vowels = { "0", "a", "A", "e", "E", "i", "I", "o",
        "O", "u", "U", "y", "Y" };
String[] cons = { "0", "b", "B", "c", "C", "d", "D", "f", "F",
        "g", "G", "h", "H", "j", "J", "k", "K", "l", "L", "m",
        "M", "n", "N", "p", "P", "q", "Q", "r", "R", "s", "S",
        "t", "T", "v", "V", "w", "W", "x", "X", "z", "Z" };

String c = String.join("", cons);
String v = String.join("", vowels);
    
String[] testData = { "I Love Apples\n",
        "To be or not to be that is the question!\n",
        "This also handles (parens) and `single` and \"double\" quotes\n" };
    
// this section iterates over the phrases and encodes them, storing the values in
// a StringBuilder
List<String> coded = new ArrayList<>();
for (String text : testData) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char ch = text.charAt(i);
        int index = v.indexOf(ch);
        if (index >= 0) {
            sb.append("V").append(index);
            continue;
        }
        index = c.indexOf(ch);
        if (index >= 0) {
            sb.append("C").append(index);
            continue;
        }
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    coded.add(sb.toString());
}
    
for (String code : coded) {
    System.out.println(code);
}
// Now simply search on encoded values or a single character. Keep finding the
// pattern and converting back to a letter.  Punctuation is preserved.
String pat = "([CV]\\d+|.)";
for (String code : coded) {
    StringBuilder plain = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pat).matcher(code);
    while (m.find()) {
        String group = m.group();
        if (group.charAt(0) == 'V') {
            plain.append(v.charAt(
                    Integer.valueOf(group.substring(1))));
        } else if (group.charAt(0) == 'C') {
            plain.append(c.charAt(
                    Integer.valueOf(group.substring(1))));
        } else {
            plain.append(group);
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(plain);
}
```

The above prints first the encoded strings, then the decoded strings.

```
V6 C18V7C33V3 V2C23C23C17V3C29

C32V7 C1V3 V7C27 C21V7C31 C31V7 C1V3 C31C11V1C31 V5C29 C31C11V3 C25V9V3C29C31V5V
7C21!

C32C11V5C29 V1C17C29V7 C11V1C21C5C17V3C29 (C23V1C27V3C21C29) V1C21C5 `C29V5C21C9
C17V3` V1C21C5 "C5V7V9C1C17V3" C25V9V7C31V3C29

I Love Apples
To be or not to be that is the question!
This also handles (parens) and `single` and "double" quotes
```